# VueJs: How to change CSS background image for each page route?

Tags: vuejs2, gridsome

I am probably making this more complicated than it needs to be, but does anyone have any ideas on how I can swap out custom banner images for each of my pages (when route changes to any thing other than index page)? ***I have the slots working , but need way to change background image in the non-index banners.*** Here's my code:

> `App.vue` and shows only the main page banner:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <BannerHome v-if="isHomeView" />
    <main id="routerView">
      <RouterView :key="$route.fullPath" />
    </main>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BannerHome from '@/components/BannerHome.vue'
import Footer from '@/components/Footer.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    BannerHome,
    Footer
  },
  computed: {
    isHomeView() {
      return this.$route.fullPath === '/'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

> Example of non-index page (`About.vue`):

```
<template>
  <article>
    <banner>
      <template v-slot:titleTop>Mission Focused</template>
      <template v-slot:titleBottom>
        Dedicated To Service
      </template>
    </banner>
    <section class="container-md pb-5">
      <h1>About Page</h1>
    </section>
  </article>
</template>

<script>
import Banner from '@/components/Banner.vue'
export default {
  name: 'About',
  components: {
    Banner
  }
}
</script>
```

> Banner component for non-index pages (`Banner.vue`). ***Note the background image. How can I swap this out for each non-index page? Right now the background image is shown for ALL non-index pages.***

```
<template>
<header>
  <MainNav />
    <div class="container">
    <h1><em><slot name="titleTop"></slot><br />
    <span class="pl-3"><slot name="titleBottom"></slot></span></em>
      </h1>
  </div>
</header>
</template>

<script>
import MainNav from '@/components/MainNav.vue'
export default {
    name: 'Banner',
  components: {
    MainNav
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  // set this page height here
  height: 20em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
header::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 6em;
    width: 100%;
  // set this page height here
    height: calc(20em + 10em);
    z-index: -1;
    transform: skewY(-3.5deg);
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),
        url('../assets/mockphoto.jpg') < -----how to swap out this image?
            no-repeat left top,
        linear-gradient(#4e4376, #2b5876);
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom: 0.2em solid #fff;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1.75rem!important;
    font-weight: 700!important;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
    padding: 2.5rem 0 0 0;
    // text-shadow: 0.022em 0.022em 0.022em #111;
    color: #fff;
}

</style>
```

*Btw, I am also using Gridsome...so if there is also an easy way to access page data via GraphQL for this purpose I can also use that. Thanks for any help !*

Answer (score 1):

So, I actually just need to add the `/deep/` keyword to the parent CSS like so:

```
/deep/ header::before {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),
        url('../assets/mockphoto.jpg')
            no-repeat left top,
        linear-gradient(#4e4376, #2b5876);
}
```

Docs: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors